# LogCat Error : No adapter Attached. Skipping layout. onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am working on a app that extracts news content from the site and display in the recyclerview (inside fragment).

I am getting logcat error stating "No adapter attached, skipping layout". I can see data in logcat but cannot display in recyclerview.

code till now:

```
private class NewsExtractor extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
String title;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        Document doc = null;

            while (status == OK) {
                currentURL = url + String.valueOf(page);

                //add the page number to the url
                try {
                    response = Jsoup.connect(currentURL)
                            .execute();  //you may add here userAgent/timeout etc.
                    status = response.statusCode();
                    if (status == OK) {
                        doc = response.parse();

                        Elements urlLists = doc.select("a[rel=bookmark]");
                        for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element urlList : urlLists) {

                            String src = urlList.text();
                            Log.d("NEWS",src);
                            myLinks.add(src);


                        }
                    }

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                page++;
            }
        return null;
      }

  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        myRecyclerViewAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),myLinks);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);


    }
}
```

...

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);
    int i = getArguments().getInt(NEWS);
    String topics = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.topics)[i];

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyNews);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
   switch (i) {
        case 0:
            url = "http://myagdikali.com/category/sport-news/page/";
            new NewsExtractor().execute();

    }
    return rootView;
   }
```

Code for RecyclerViewAdapter

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder>{

private ArrayList<String> myLinks;
private Context mContext;

public  MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> myLinks) {
    this.myLinks = myLinks;
    this.mContext = context;
}


@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
    CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.textView.setText(myLinks.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myLinks.size();
}

public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView textView;

    public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
         this.textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }
}
```

}
And the thing is, I am able to display content from a single page only (not using loop NewsExtractor up)

Comment: Just set the adapter in `onCreateView` later you can update mylinks and refresh adapter

Comment: Can u please describe more? @Raghunandan

Comment: setting adapter didn't help.. Still getting the same error @Raghunandan

Comment: set your layout manager first then the bind adapter to recyclerview later. you can do those in `onCreateView`. You can update you mylinks in onPostExccute and refresh your adapter